# Outlook end of meeting reminder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, notifications, reminder, meetings

Is there a way to make Outlook show a reminder when a meeting is *ending*?

Sometimes I schedule meetings for myself to focus on one specific task for an hour or so, and it would be very useful to be reminded to get back to other tasks when the allocated time expires.

Answer (score 1):

Two options I can think of:

1. Set the reminder time specifically when the appointment start reminder pops up; or
2. Try to write yourselve a macro that fiddles with the reminder time automagically

Answer (score 1):

The only workaround I can think of would be to schedule a 0 minute meeting immediately after the one you want an end of meeting reminder for.

Answer (score 0):

There's an app for iOS now that might be the right solution for you:

Meeting End Reminders
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/meeting-end-reminders/id1291619732?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

The "VALARM" calendar component MUST only appear within either a "VEVENT" or "VTODO" calendar component. "VALARM" calendar components cannot be nested. Multiple mutually independent "VALARM" calendar components can be specified for a single "VEVENT" or "VTODO" calendar component.

The "TRIGGER" property specifies when the alarm will be triggered. The "TRIGGER" property specifies a duration prior to the start of an event or a to-do. The "TRIGGER" edge may be explicitly set to be relative to the "START" or "END" of the event or to-do with the "RELATED" parameter of the "TRIGGER" property. The "TRIGGER" property value type can alternatively be set to an absolute calendar date and time of day value.

In an alarm set to trigger on the "START" of an event or to-do, the "DTSTART" property MUST be present in the associated event or to-do. In an alarm in a "VEVENT" calendar component set to trigger on the "END" of the event, either the "DTEND" property MUST be present, or the "DTSTART" and "DURATION" properties MUST both be present. In an alarm in a "VTODO" calendar component set to trigger on the "END" of the to-do, either the "DUE" property MUST be present, or the "DTSTART" and "DURATION" properties MUST both be present.

Comment: I'm suspect there's a valid solution to the question in there somewhere. Unfortunately it seems to be drowning in a sea of waffle ;-)